# Trouble Finding Spectrum Peaks on Python/ Google Colab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, data-analysis, spectra

I have a spectrum (of an oil sample) as a 2D array in a cvs file that i want to find the peaks for in wavelengths 600 - 1800 cm-1. I've tried the scipy.signal.find_peaks but that takes a 1D array and I have a 2D array with the wavelengths and corresponding peak values.
any help would be appreactiated since im very beginner at python

Edit: I also tried doing the following:

from detecta import detect_peaks

ind = detect_peaks(df)

where df is the name of my array (which has two columns) and an error pops up: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scipy.signal.find_peaks()` only takes a one-dimensional array containing the peaks. So you should be able to just select the column in your DataFrame with the peaks as so:

```
# note that find_peaks returns an array of peak indices, and a dictionary of properties 
ind, properties = scipy.signal.find_peaks(df["name of column with peaks"])
```

Then if you only want the peaks, select the rows using the ind array you just created:

```
peak_df = df[df.index.isin(ind)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i put this in and it didnt come out with any peaks, the output was: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [cm, A]
Index: []

Comment: was `ind` populated with indexes from `find_peaks()`?

Comment: i think so?  this is my code: ind = scipy.signal.find_peaks(df["cm"]) 
peak_df = df[df.index.isin(ind)]
print(peak_df)

Comment: use the `"A"` column, not the `"cm"` column. cm surely refers to the ascending wavelengths (where there will be no peaks) and A the Amplitudes

Comment: Yes sorry my bad. I changed it to the A column and it is still giving me the same output

Comment: oh sorry, `find_peaks` returns 2 things, the list of indices and then a dict of properties. so either do `...isin(ind[0])` or `ind, properties = scipy.signal.find_peaks(...`

Comment: no worries. please accept this as the answer if it solved your problem